# Magento 2: How to remove attributes of the customer in the backend?

Tags: magento2, attributes, customer, backend

I need remove from customer addresses the next attributes: Prefix, Middle name and Suffix.

[image]

How I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `customer_form.xml` file to custom module

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_form.xml
```

With below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="address">
        <field name="prefix" formElement="input">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    <field name="middlename" formElement="input">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    <field name="suffix" formElement="input">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

It would be remove above fields from customer address in Admin.

Comment: Nice, it work, but i remove **formElement="input"**, this gave me error. I don't know the motive

Comment: not working in magento240 version